# Basic Prolog Nth Number of Tribonacci Series

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

In my Principles of Programming class we have started learning Prolog, and we were tasked with creating a query trib(N, T) which is true if T is the Nth Tribonacci number, with the series 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, (etc...).  I have written what I would have believed to return the answer:

```
addThis(Count, X, Y, Z, Goal) :-
     ( Count == 1, Goal == 0 ->  
        true;
     Count == 2, Goal == 0 ->  
        true;                             
     Count == 3, Z \== Goal ->  
        false;
     Count == 3, Z == Goal ->
        true;
    Count \== 3, Z \== Goal ->  
        X is X+Y+Z, Count is Count - 1,
         addThis(Count, Y, Z, X, Goal)).

trib(N, T) :- addThis(N, 0, 0, 1, T).
```

Whereas, if N = 1 and T = 0 it is true, N = 2 and T = 0 is true, if N = 3 and Z = T it is true, and if N = 3 but Z != T then it must be false.  This is done through the last recursive if statement, where as long as Count is not 3 and Z is not equal to the Goal (T), then X should be equal to X+Y+Z to obtain the next number in the sequence, and the Count is reduced by 1.  Unfortunately, unless it is in the parameters of the static condition statements it returns false.  Why is this?

Comment: I didn't read your code deeply, but at least   " X is X+Y+Z" part is obviously invalid. All variables in righthand side of "is"  must be number.

Comment: and "Count is Count - 1" part,too. When prolog variable is bound to a value, it cannot be changed without backtracking.

Comment: You're writing Prolog as if it were a transliteration of a language like C. Not a good idea. Prolog is very different. For one thing, you dn't "assign" variables like other languages. They are bound based upon *unification of terms*. `X is X+Y+Z` will always fail unless the value of `X` literally is the value of `X+Y+Z`. In other words, if `Y+Z` add up to zero.

Comment: Of interest: Tribonacci numbers - OEIS [A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073)

Answer (score 0):

Your `trib/2` is good, but you have to rewrite your `addThis/5`:

```
% Where X,Y,Z are the three first elements of the Tribonacci sequence:

% Prototype: addThis(N, X, Y, Z, NthElement)

addThis(0, X,_Y,_Z,X). % returns the 0th element
addThis(1,_X, Y,_Z,Y). % returns the 1st element
addThis(2,_X,_Y, Z,Z). % returns the 2nd element

% returns the sum of the three elements
% i.e. the fourth element
addThis(3,X,Y,Z,Next):-
    Next is X+Y+Z.

% returns the Nth element recursively
addThis(N,X,Y,Z,Next):-
    N > 3,
    NewN is N-1,
    W is X+Y+Z,
    addThis(NewN,Y,Z,W,Next).

trib(N,Goal):-
    addThis(N,0,0,1,Goal).
```